# Creating Polygons with Huge Data Using Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to display a population density map about Turkey on Google Maps and I have the GeoJson file to create the polygons. Displaying the whole layer as one is pretty simple and considerably fast. But I do need to fill those polygons using the polygon's name. The code that I'm using to display the polygon as a whole is down below.

```
provinces_of_turkey = new google.maps.Data(); // POLYGON FOR PROVINCES
        provinces_of_turkey.loadGeoJson(
          'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/oividioscaeremos/5905f9632a1c0ae92c5eb52d1cc40dce/raw/42accdc50510444017c52f3be141b70f706af8e3/provinces_of_turkey.json'
        );
        provinces_of_turkey.setStyle(function (feature) {
          return ({
            fillColor: '#FF8686',
            zIndex: 3,
            fillOpacity: .0,
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeWeight: 1
          });
        });
        provinces_of_turkey.setMap(map);
```

And as of now, I need to display those polygons individually with different fill-colors.I can display some polygons using the code showed below, but displaying the whole map in this format crashes the browser so I need another solution. If I could turn my coordinates array to google.maps.LatLng array quickly, my problem would be solved.

What I'm using to display each polygon individually;

```
fetch(
      'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/oividioscaeremos/5905f9632a1c0ae92c5eb52d1cc40dce/raw/42accdc50510444017c52f3be141b70f706af8e3/provinces_of_turkey.json'
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      response.json().then(function (results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
          if(results.features[i].geometry.type == "MultiPolygon"){
            continue;
          }
          var paths = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < results.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0].length; i++) {
            var coordinates = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][i];
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
            paths.push(latLng);
          }
          provinces_of_turkey = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: paths,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
          });
          provinces_of_turkey.setMap(map);
        }
      });
    });
```

How can I do the fillcolor for each polygon without crashing the browser? (I need to do it with using google maps javascript api because on the same map I'm displaying some other data as well.)

Comment: Have you looked at [dynamic styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#change_appearance_dynamically) of the Data Layer?

Comment: I have but since I have districts layer on the map addition to the provinces layer, I don't really know how to implement, I'll look into that more deeply and write some feedback probably tomorrow. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hey, I had to change my json file a bit but I got it to work. Thank you for your suggestion, helped me a lot :)